# Is there a built-in function in GLSL for AND or is there some optimized method for doing component wise AND?

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader

GLSL has component wise functions for `lessThan`, `greaterThan`, etc, which return a `bvec`.

There's also `any()` and `all()`, but there seems to be no `and()`.

If I have two `bvec3`s and want a new `bvec3`, equivalent to:

```
bvec3 new = bvec3(two.x && one.x, two.y && one.y, two.z && one.z);
```

Is there a faster way or more optimized way to do this?

I'm trying to write highly optimized GLSL code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure at all if this would be more efficient, but I believe you could do the `and` of two `bvec3` values by converting them to another vector type like `uvec3` or `vec3`, use the more extensive operations on those types (like bitwise and, multiplication), and then convert back.

With your `bvec3` values `one` and `two`, these are a few options:

```
bvec3(uvec3(one) & uvec3(two))
bvec3(uvec3(one) * uvec3(two))
bvec3(vec3(one) * vec3(two))
```

You should definitely benchmark before using this. There's a good chance that the component-wise expression is faster.

Answer (score 1):

On Nvidia GPUs you can just write `bvec3 new = two && one;`.

The specification is confusing on this. It states

> The logical binary operators and (&&), or ( | | ), and exclusive or (^^) operate only on two Boolean
> expressions and result in a Boolean expression

and throughout it lists `bvec*` as "Boolean types". Like here

> It is a compile-time error to declare a vertex shader input containing any of the
> following:
>
> - A Boolean type (bool, bvec2, bvec3, bvec4)

The glslang compiler does not interpret the spec this way and will give you a compile error.